# How to declare variable type for code generation in MATLAB

Tags: c, matlab, code-generation, simulink

Consider the following variable declaration in C code:

```
Counter_Type counter_var;
```

It is a C code that a `counter_var` is defined with a specific type `Counter_Type`.

my question is: How it would be possible to declare a variable type which is used inside a MATLAB function in Simulink lead the generated code generates that variable with that specific type.

For instance consider the following code which is a simple odd number adder written in MATLAB as a MATLAB  fucntion:

```
function Sum = sum_oddfcn(N)
Sum = 0; count = 1;
while ne(count,N)
    if mod(count,2) ~= 0
        Sum = Sum + count;
    end
    count = count + 1;
end
end
```

Now I want to know if there is a way to declare the `count` variable declared in the above function to be generated with a type of `Custom_Type` variable.

Answer (score 0):

you can use add parameter in matlab function and define datatype in base workspace.